# what is the difference between diameter "GY" and "RO" interface

Tags: diameter-protocol

Can someone tell me about the difference between GY and RO interfaces used by diameter protocol ???

As per my understanding both of this interfaces looks pretty similar and the AVP's used too.

But still i understand that there is a difference..

Answer (score 9):

**Ro** is a 3GPP reference point that describes the connection to the OCS from another functional component. It is a general term that covers multiple connecting components such as GGSN, P-GW, WLAN, IMS AS, MBMS server, etc.

**Gy** is an specific instance of the Ro reference point that connects a charging component from the packet-switched domain (PS domain) i.e. PCEF within a GGSN or P-GW to the OCS

For more [details](http://www.developingsolutions.com/products/ro-interface/)

Answer (score 2):

There are different 3GPP specification for each of the interfaces.
You can read the differences and see the specifications here:

http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/dime/current/msg05723.html